# 10 $digest() iterations reached when using filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm try to use filter `| filter: {pro: value}`, but I have a very strange error : [Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20regularInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22day%22%3A1%2C%22hour_start%22%3A1000%2C%22hour_end%22%3A1800%2C%22pro_id%22%3A1%2C%22office_id%22%3A1%2C%22authorized_pros%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22visibility%22%3A3%2C%22authorize_all%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%5B%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%5D%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20regularInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20regularInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20regularInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20regularInterceptedExpression%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%5B%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%5D%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22%3C%3Calready%20seen%3E%3E%22%7D%5D%5D)...

In my controller, I just have `$scope.slots = […]`.

My view is very simple : `<div time-slots="slots | filter: {day:1}"></div>`.

My directive is just  `templateUrl: 'time-slot.html', restrict: 'A', scope: { timeSlots: '=' }`.

I'm totally lost with this error ... I don't understand what's wrong with my code. Here a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eS4pvKXf2chg4qoxtSFI?p=preview)

Did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot explain what's going on, but to avoid this problem you can pass previously filtered value to your directive

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
    //$scope.slots = [.......]
    $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.slots,{day:1});
});
```

html:

```
<div time-slots="filtered"></div>
```

Or filter it inside directive for example in this way:

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="day">
  <div ng-repeat="slot in timeSlots | filter:{day:day}">
    <pre>{{slot|json}}</pre>

  </div>

</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JLfIuP9oVQ9cwo3i54UA?p=preview

Or in link function with:

```
$scope.timeSlots= $filter('filter')($scope.timeSlots,{day:1});
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that expression "slots | filter: {day:1}" always returns a new array and when the $digest loop runs again, it is interpreted as changed.

Answer (score 7):

You're creating an infinite sequence of `$digest`s by using the following combination:

- an isolated scope with `=` binding,
- an expression with a filter passing into that binding.

Keep in mind that the `=` binding works *both ways* and that application of a filter creates a new collection. Thus, the following happens:

1. Outer scope collection `A` is filtered, creating collection `B`, that is passed into the directive. Through the two-way `=` binding, it is set back on the outer scope, replacing `A`.
2. Outer scope collection `B` is filtered, creating collection `C`, that is passed into the directive. ...
3. ...

When AngularJS finds out that `$digest`s are going round and round and still more are needed, it breaks with the abovementioned error.